# Strange CSV header whitespace handling

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-5.1

I am wondering how exactly PowerShell handles (unquoted) whitespace in CSV headers...

Consider this simple example:

```
ConvertFrom-Csv @"
Foo;
Bar
"@ -Delim ";" | select "Foo"
```

Works like a charm. Now, when I add a space to the header, it will be preserved:

```
ConvertFrom-Csv @"
Foo ;
Bar
"@ -Delim ";" | select "Foo "
```

Fair enough. But when I add more spaces, there will still be **only one** space at the end of the property name:

```
ConvertFrom-Csv @"
Foo   ;
Bar
"@ -Delim ";" | select "Foo "
```

I was thinking, maybe PowerShell replaces multiple consecutive spaces with a single space, to clean up headers that consist of multiple words, but no:

```
ConvertFrom-Csv @"
Foo   Bar;
Hello
"@ -Delim ";" | select "Foo   Bar"
```

Even stranger: Now, *any* amount of spaces at the end seem to be preserved, and the strange "single space" behavior disappears:

```
ConvertFrom-Csv @"
Foo   Bar   ;
Hello
"@ -Delim ";" | select "Foo   Bar   "
```

Also, note that any *leading* spaces are apparently always trimmed. But I have not made many more tests so far.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

I couldn't find any documentation. It would make sense if all white-space was either always preserved, or always trimmed. But this behavior is very confusing to work with. `Import-Csv` seems to have the same behavior btw.

*(Version: PowerShell 5.1)*

**EDIT**

Note that I *do not own* the CSV. It's provided by a client. I know it is possible to quote headers, but this is about the *handling* of an existing CSV, not how to *modify* it. I know how to workaround this problem, but that is not the purpose of the question.

Ideally, I was hoping PowerShell **would not** keep any of the trailing white-space, so I am wondering why it does at all, because that makes it more difficult to work with.

Comment: This is a really `ConvertFrom-Csv`/`Import-Csv` ***cmdlet*** specific question. Honestly, I would border too much about this as I would simply quote `csv` headers if they have any (leading or tailing) spaces (also for readabiliy), e.g. `' " Foo  Bar " '; ...`. In that case, there is no discussion whether the spaces are part of a header or the delimiter.

Comment: Of course  it's about these two **cmdlets**, as I stated in the question. That is pretty much all there is to PowerShell's built-in CSV handling. Also, note my edit. I know it's possible to quote headers, but that's not the point.

Comment: You might consider to send your feedback on the [documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues) or (based on @Danny_ds answer) [purpose a (break?) change on the cmdlets](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Spaces around a (unquoted) field [should](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) be preserved, but in reality parsers can differ.

> Spaces are considered part of a field and should not be ignored.

Probably the best way to preserve them is to surround the field with double quotes:

```
" Foo   Bar   ";
```

Just make sure there are no spaces between the separator and the double quotes or things might even get stranger :)

Comment: Please note the edit in my question. The question is **not** "How to preserve whitespace", because of course I know I can use quotes. And again, as you stated yourself .. what if there **are** spaces between the quotes and the delimiters...?

Comment: Interesting to read about the specification for this case though.

Comment: As for "_spaces between the quotes and the delimiters_", I think this could be seen as 'undefined behaviour'. Different parsers will produce different results and some will give an error.